# XPath for all elements not with certain parent

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0, xpath-1.0

Let's say I have the following XML:

```
<div>
   <a>
      <label>a</label>
   </a>
   <b>
      <label>b</label>
   </b>
   <c>
      <d>
         <label>c-d</label>
      </d>
   </c>
   <b>
      <d>
         <label>b-d</label>
      </d>
   </b>
</div>
```

I am trying to use Xpath to find all "label" elements, but not inside the `<b>` tags.
In this example, I would want to get

```
<label>a</label>
<label>c-d</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to get all the labels which are not inside the `b` tag.

Try with the below xpath.

```
//div//label[not(ancestor::b)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This XPath,

```
//label[not(parent::b)]
```

selects all `label` elements without a `b` ***parent*** per your title.

This XPath,

```
//label[not(ancestor::b)]
```

selects all `label` elements without a `b` ***ancestor*** per your examples.